# Como definir um atributo ao form pai de determinado input?

Tags: jquery

Tenho o seguinte formulário:

```
<form id="excluir" class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="s59zI8Ehg0dw2CVnmqpfGgyyuHKJDHSF">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
</form>
```

Atualmente estou utilizando a instrução jQuery abaixo para atribuir um action e submeter o form:

```
$('#excluir').attr('action', '/post/12');
$('#excluir').submit();
```

Porém, não quero utilizar uma tag **id** no form, quero verificar se no form existe um input com a tag **name="_method"**, se sim, vou atribuir o action e submeter o form.

Alguma ideia de como fazer essa busca?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes fazer assim:

```
$('input[name="_method"]').closest('form').attr('action', '/post/12').submit();
```

Por passos:

- identifica o input com `name="_method"`
- procura a `form` onde esse input está dentro
- muda o atributo `action`
- envia o `form`

Answer (score 1):

```
var inputs = $("input[name=_method]");
if(inputs.length > 0) {
    var form = inputs.parent();
    form.attr("action", "/post/12");
    form.submit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pode tentar essa solucao, um pouco mais de codigo, mas ao utilizar seletores em cadeia, vc acaba deixando a performance do software/site mais lenta.
Algo que ajuda tambem eh sempre utilizar variaveia e deixar os elementos salvos em memoria uma vez que ja foram utilizados.

Eu particularmente iria com este modelo.

Espero ter ajudado.

```
// CHANGES FORM DEFAULT BEHAVIOUR
function applyFormActions( callback ) {

    var formAction = '/post/12';

    // FIND FOR ANY ELEMENT WHICH HAS THE GIVEN ATTRIBUTE
    var hasMethod = $('[name="_method"]'); // [attrName = "value"]

    if( hasMethod.lenght ){
        // GETS ELEMENT WRAPPED FORM
        var form = hasMethod.parents('form');

        // ADD ANY ACTION TO THE FORM
        form.attr('action', formAction);

        form.on('submit', function (event) {
            // IN CASE YOU ARE USING ANY OTHER ELEMENT APART FROM A BUTTON.

            event.preventDefault();

            if( typeof callback === 'function' && callback ){
                callback();
            }

        });
    }   
}
// CALL THE FUNCTION
applyFormActions( custonActionForm );

// CALLBACK FUNCTION
custonActionForm(){
    // YOUR CUSTOM ACTION FOR THE FORM
    alert(1);
};
```

Comment: Tanto código... para que é preciso a callback? Em que caso é que é preciso a segunda verificação aqui `typeof callback === 'function' && callback` ?

Comment: Se o callback for undefined ou diferente de function, vai dar um erro.

Comment: O que eu queria dizer é que basta `if( typeof callback === 'function'){` pois se `callback` fôr uma `function` a segunda condição do `&&` está garantida, ie é redundante.